# How stateless components are optimised in React v16.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In the react docs, I read:

> This pattern is designed to encourage the creation of these simple
>   components that should comprise large portions of your apps. In the
>   future, we’ll also be able to make performance optimizations specific
>   to these components by avoiding unnecessary checks and memory
>   allocations.

There are several discussions on github like [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/5677) but these are quite old, what I want to ask is if there are any optimisations done in React v16.0 or before for functional components like implicit `shouldComponentUpdate` etc. and if these optimisations are done then what are those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any Optimizations done on the stateless components yet as of v16.0.0 is concerned. The changes that are done from v15 yo v16 are

`fragments`, `error boundaries`, `portals`, `support for custom DOM attributes`, `improved server-side rendering`, and `reduced file size`.

You can see the **[React Blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#better-server-side-rendering)** for more details on this changes

Answer (score 2):

So there isn't any official documentation for FSC (functional stateless components) performance gains over class components. But, I came across [this well written medium article](https://medium.com/missive-app/45-faster-react-functional-components-now-3509a668e69f) that explains how you can get performance gains using FSC.

> TLDR: Directly calling functional components as functions instead of mounting them using React.createElement is much faster.

For instance, a FSC looks like this:

```
const Avatar = (props) => {
  return <img src={props.url} />;
}
```

The way we usually use these components is with the JSX component syntax:

```
<Avatar url="/path" />
```

But, through some careful benchmarking and exploration, the author was able to get ~45% speed improvement by calling the FSC as a **function**:

> Instead of mounting them as components, let’s just call them as what they really are: plain JavaScript functions.

```
Avatar({ url: "/path" });
```

I think getting performance gains from this method really depends on your app structure, but I thought that it was a neat trick that could potentially be really useful.

Answer (score 1):

The only current optimization that I am aware of is that instance objects of stateless components are never created nor retained.  So one less object gets created and stored in memory per rendered instance.